# redundant parameter type info in partially applied function definition

Tags: scala

```
def foo(num:Int, str:String):Int = 1

val bar = foo(3, _)  // compiler complains "missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => test(3, x$1))"

val baz = foo(3, _:String) // compiles fine
```

Why do I have to explicitly specify the type of _ when it looks inferrable from the context?

**EDIT**: Renamed to avoid name collision following David Soergel's suggest.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, to avoid confusion between "def test" and "val test", let's write:

```
def foo(num:Int, str:String):Int = 1

val bar = foo(3, _)  // compiler complains "missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => foo(3, x$1))"

val baz = foo(3, _:String) // compiles fine
```

What's inferrable from context is only that the argument to bar must somehow be convertible to a String.  That could be due to inheritance (if instead of String you use some non-final type there), or due to an implicit conversion.

Basically the potential for implicits means that the argument to bar could be just about any type at all, so the code as written is indeed underspecified.  I don't know whether the compiler actually checks whether there are any appropriate implicit conversions in scope before issuing the "missing type" error, but I would guess not.  (In the case of String there are likely to be a bunch present, anyway).  It would be brittle and confusing if the signature of baz changed as a result of importing a new implicit that could produce a String.

Comment: Thanks for the name correction. But `def foo(num:Int) = 1; val bar = foo(_)` compiles fine. So I don't think inheritance or implicit conversions cause the error.

Comment: Huh-- sorry, on further reflection my argument about implicits makes no sense anyway.  The compiler could indeed just infer the type of the bar argument to be String, and then allow implicits when calling bar, as usual.

Answer (score 3):

I think David Soergel's explanation is essentially correct: if type `T` has an implicit conversion to String then `val bar = foo(3, _:T)` is valid, giving a function of type `T => Int`, which is unrelated to `String => Int`.

Why the compiler doesn't make a sensible assumption (in the absence of explicit typing) that the type is in fact the same as in the method (which is the essence of your question), I don't know - I can only guess it's because it would complicate the language spec.

Where no types are specified, i.e. `val bar = foo(_, _)`, it seems the compiler interprets it as simple eta-conversion, the same as `val bar = foo _`, which does give a `String => Int`.

My preferred idiom would be to give the function type on the left hand side, which has the benefit of allowing you to easily see `bar`'s type:

```
val bar: String => Int = foo(3, _)
```

If you're allergic to re-typing the word `String`, you could write

```
val bar = (foo _).curried(3)
```

Comment: "Placeholder Syntax for Anonymous Functions" part of scala spec(2.8) gives no information about how type of "_" is inferred. Lack of spec might be the cause of this compiler inconsistency.